# Decrypting in Java with Blowfish

Tags: java, cryptography, encryption, blowfish

Hullo,

I am encrypting and decrypting in Java with Blowfish.

The encryption works fine, but the decryption fails.

Here is my Java code for decrypting :

```
String encryptedString = … ;
String decryptedString = null;
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(myKey.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
Cipher cipher;
try {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedString.getBytes());
    decryptedString = new String(decrypted, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
} [ catch Exceptions … ]
```

I get an exception :

`Exception. javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher`

Can you tell me how to make this simply work ? Thank you.

The input I give comes from my encryption Java code, + encoding in Base64, and I decode it from Base64 just before giving it to this decrypting operation.

Comment: The encoded data have to come in blocks of 8 bits. If you have say 22 bits, you use padding for the extra 2 when encrypting. THis is the whole idea with block ciphers. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29

Comment: @John — That does not help me much. I have edited my post to be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have the solution !

First, there were some problems with Unicode, so I have put ISO-8859-1 everywhere. [Including in the Base64 encoding and decoding.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10319155/1824094)

Then, I have juggled with the variants.

Here is my Java code which works for Blowfish decryption :

```
String encryptedString = … ;
String decryptedString = null;
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(myKey.getBytes(CHARSET_ISO_8859_1), "Blowfish");
Cipher cipher;
try {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedString.getBytes(CHARSET_ISO_8859_1));
    decryptedString = new String(decrypted, CHARSET_ISO_8859_1);
} [ catch Exceptions … ]
```

Note that I have replaced `"Blowfish"` with `"Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding"` for getting the `Cipher` instance, but, if you do the same for the key, it fails.

The key `myKey` has to be a Latin-1 string of 8 characters. This makes a key of 128 bits. The Blowfish algorithm allows bigger keys, but they fail in Java because of the USA export restriction in the JRE — the USA allow encryption but not stronger than what the [NSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NSA) can break.

The `CHARSET_ISO_8859_1` is a constant defined like this :

```
final Charset CHARSET_ISO_8859_1 = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
```

And `Charset` is `java.nio.charset.Charset`.

Last but not least, I have changed my encryption Java code accordingly.

Comment: Nah, this is wrong and is a poor example that nobody should follow. The fact that ISO-8859-1 encoding works is simply luck. The output of encryption is not a valid string in any character set and should not be encoded as such. If you must do so use a valid binary-to-text encoding such as base64 encoding.

Comment: @Greg — You missed an episode — I edited my post. The encoding, UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1, has to be there. It does not replace Base64. In this page I focus on the Blowfish decryption, and encryption. I do Base64 coding after encryption, and Base64 decoding before decryption. But I left these steps out of my Java codes in this page.

Comment: You have to remember that your answer stands, not just for yourself, but for others who come here with similar questions (perhaps by Googling). So, when I see the line `byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedString.getBytes(CHARSET_ISO_8859_1));` I see a poor practice. The fact that the line does not actually exist in your program is irrelevant.

Comment: @sana — Use a key `myKey` of only 8 chars.

Answer (score 10):

Converting bytes to hex and back is tricky. This should solve your problem. (You need to fix your string representation of encryptedString)

**Output:**

```
StackOverflow 537461636B4F766572666C6F77 [83, 116, 97, 99, 107, 79, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119]
J~3¹ÙÂÖ"¢ª„¨u 194A7E33B9060CD9C2D622A2AA84A875 [25, 74, 126, 51, -71, 6, 12, -39, -62, -42, 34, -94, -86, -124, -88, 117]
StackOverflow 537461636B4F766572666C6F77 [83, 116, 97, 99, 107, 79, 118, 101, 114, 102, 108, 111, 119]
```

**Code:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
    SecretKey secretkey = keygenerator.generateKey();

    String plaintextString = "StackOverflow";
    System.out.println(plaintextString + " " + bytesToHex(plaintextString.getBytes()) + " " + Arrays.toString(plaintextString.getBytes()));

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(secretkey.getEncoded(), "Blowfish");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintextString.getBytes());
    String encryptedString = bytesToHex(encrypted);
    System.out.println(new String(encrypted) + " " + encryptedString + " " + Arrays.toString(encrypted));

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(encryptedString));
    String decryptedString = bytesToHex(decrypted);
    System.out.println(new String(decrypted) + " " + decryptedString + " " + Arrays.toString(decrypted));

  }

  public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
      return null;
    } else if (str.length() < 2) {
      return null;
    } else {
      int len = str.length() / 2;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 16);
      }
      return buffer;
    }

  }

  public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data) {
    if (data == null) {
      return null;
    } else {
      int len = data.length;
      String str = "";
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if ((data[i] & 0xFF) < 16)
          str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i] & 0xFF);
        else
          str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i] & 0xFF);
      }
      return str.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sanchit, but this is way too complicated. See my coming answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your myKey variable lenght must be multiple of 8

Comment: My key is a string of 16 characters, so this makes a key of 128 bits.

Comment: A character is not necessarily 8 bits. The encryption key is binary data and you're bound to run into problems if you try to store it in a string without using a suitable encoding like base64.

Answer (score 1):

```
String encryptedString = … ;  
String decryptedString = null;
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(myKey.getBytes(), "Blowfish");
private static byte[] linebreak = {}; // Remove Base64 encoder default linebreak
private static Base64 coder;
Cipher cipher;
try {
    coder = new Base64(32, linebreak, true);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedString.getBytes());
    decryptedString = new String(coder.encode(decrypted));
} [ catch Exceptions … ]
```

You can use Base64 class to solve this problem.

Comment: I already had Base64 encoding and decoding. So I don't think this was the problem. See my coming answer. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely be more explicit with the `Cipher` by declaring the mode and padding. How is this code getting encrypted? What is actually in the `String` `encryptedString`? Is it hex encoded or base64 encoded? If it isn't encoded that could definitely be a source of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private byte[] encrypt(String key, String plainText) throws GeneralSecurityException {

    SecretKey secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITM);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITM);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret_key);

    return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
}
```

here you can find whole class with enc/dec --- http://dexxtr.com/post/57145943236/blowfish-encrypt-and-decrypt-in-java-android

Comment: Thank you Dexxtr, but I have solved the problem now. See my self-answer.

Comment: I am sure this would not work. `ALGORITM` would not exist. And I have a big doubt about `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE`, for decrypting.

Answer (score 0):

try {
/**
* Initialize the cipher for decryption
*/
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
/**
* Initialize input and output streams
*/
inStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile);
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
outStream.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, len));
outStream.flush();
}
outStream.write(cipher.doFinal());
inStream.close();
outStream.close();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        /**
         * Initialize the cipher for decryption
         */
     cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        /**
         * Initialize input and output streams
         */
        inStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile);
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outStream.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, len));
            outStream.flush();
        }
        outStream.write(cipher.doFinal());
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
    }
```

...

1. List item